# Where does Notepad++ store the clipboard history items?

Tags: notepad++, clipboard, history

In Notepad++ for a windows machine, at what file path does the clipboard history get saved? I would like to be able to save all clipboard history items in a separate txt file without using any plugins.

Couldn't find any related file in the following paths: `C:\Program Files\Notepad++` or `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Notepad++`

Also the data disappears when I restart the app. Is there a way to make a dump?

Comment: does the history disappear when you close and open notepad++ again? if so it is probably in memory. as I am using a 3rd party clipboard tool on windows, I didn't know they integrated one. I know there was a plugin you had to download/activate in the past. if it is saved on the file system, you could open process monitor from sysinternals and see what happens when you put something on the clipboard (find the file path&name).

Comment: Some data is in C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\config.xml , if you've not configured Notepad++ *on installation* to store data elsewhere.

Comment: @Zina yes. it disappears when we shut down Notepad++

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I don't see any clipboard related configs/storage path in config.xml

Comment: @DrMoishePippik any other ideas